NextJS throwing 413 Payload Too Large
There's an API route that processed a CSV file,
I have a file of size 12MB. When I upload it, it throws this error: 413 Payload Too Large
Request is too large for the server to process.
According to docs, this setting can be altered using config as,
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: '15mb',
    },
  },
};

But this throws build error,
Error: Page config in api/route.ts is deprecated. Replace `export const config=…` with the following:
Visit https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config for more information.

And this doesn't have an option to toggle the bodySizeLimit.
These docs are conflicting and confusing. Help is appreciated.

Have you checked out the serverActions.bodySizeLimit for the app router? This discussion also seems to be about your issue.

Could you share how exactly the file is being uploaded? Is this server actions or client side upload with fetch and it's hitting the api route? Are you using app or page router? Which file is this config stored in?

does this happen only on production?

The old config method was used in Next.js within the pages directory to set specific configurations for each API route. However, for Next.js 13 and later, config settings cannot be applied in this way within the app directory.
You can use for this formidable library;
Please check This
